# Get specific user from many to many associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have many to many association through UserTask table. I need to get user with type creator from task (task.creator). It should be like task.user_tasks.where(user_type: 0) but with rails associations. Is it possible?

Here is my User model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_tasks, foreign_key: 'user_email', primary_key: 'email'
  has_many :tasks, through: :user_tasks
end
```

Here is my Task model

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_tasks, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :user_tasks
end
```

Here is my UserTask model

```
class UserTask < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: 'user_email', primary_key: 'email'
  belongs_to :task
  enum user_type: [:creator, :allowed]
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it using

```
User.joins(:user_tasks).where(user_tasks: { user_type: 0 })
```